# How is "he'd better get used to it" different from "he should get used to it"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference, phrase-usage

I'm trying to understand the phrase "better get used to it". I know it basically means "he should get used to it", but is there a small difference between them? Is one more encouraging than the other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phrases to express recommendations - 'have to', 'had better' or 'should' ?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/97498/phrases-to-express-recommendations-have-to-had-better-or-should)

Comment: *He'd better not break the law* simply asserts that ***it would be better for him*** if he followed that ("practical", not "moralising") advice. But *He shouldn't break the law* strongly implies the speaker endorses the moral framework represented by "the law", and ***wants the subject to act "righteously"***.

Comment: If you say "he should get used to it" with the emphasis on 'he', most British speakers will hear it as "he ought to make an effort to become used to it", and if the emphasis is on 'should', they would hear is as "he will probably become used to it, given what we know about him".